# How to pass a sessionstorage data into header.location

Tags: jquery

here is my session data stored:

```
<script>document.write(sessionStorage.step1);</script>
```

I need to pass this session storage data into header.location like this :

```
window.location.assign("http://example.com/?value=".$sessionStorage.step1)
```

above syntax is not working. Can you please suggest me to fix this ?

Comment: It seems you are mixing up JS and PHP

Comment: can you please give me a suggestion in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use loction.href to redirect and below is the code for it.

```
location.href = 'example.com'+sessionStorage.step1
```

want to just assign it, use below

```
location.assign = location.href+sessionStorage.step1
```